graficos con tkinter matplotlib
enserio me rindo que alguien me diga que le pasa a mi código, que no es capaz de generar ningun gráfico
import math
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2Tk as Toolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


def make_plot():
    #Crear señal
    Vp = float(var_ampl.get()) #Voltios
    fre = float(var_frec.get())#Hercios
    w = 2*math.pi*fre #rad/s
    fi = float(var_fase.get())# Rad

#Graficos
def f1(t):
    return Vp*math.sin(w*t+fi)

#LIstas con datos a graficar
t = []
v = []

ciclos = 5
puntos = 30 #Puntos por ciclo
T = 1/fre  #Peridodo
deltat = T / puntos #distancia entre puntos

ti = 0 #Tiempo inical
# Calculo parejas de puntos
for i in range(puntos*ciclos+1):
    t.append(ti)
    v.append(f1(ti))

#Crear objetos en tk
#Se crea un boton
fr_grafica = tk.Frame(ventana)
fr_grafica.grid(row=1, column=0)

figure = Figure(figsize=(5,4))
fig_canvas = FigureCanvas(figure, master=fr_grafica)
fig_canvas.draw()
#Se configura para que ocupe todo
fig_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
fig_canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

#Barra de herramientas
toolbar = Toolbar(fig_canvas, fr_grafica)
toolbar.update()

#Grafico
sub_figure = figure.add_subplot(111)
sub_figure.plot(t,v)

#construcción de la ventana y sus controles
ventana = tk.Tk() #Ventana principal
ventana.title("Crear Gráfica")

#Frame para entregar entry y boton
fr_datos_entrada = tk.Frame(ventana)
fr_datos_entrada.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Amplitud
lbl_ampl = tk.Label(fr_datos_entrada, text="Amplitud [V]:")
lbl_ampl.grid(column=0, row=0)

var_ampl = tk.StringVar(value='100')
ent_ampl = tk.Entry(fr_datos_entrada, textvariable = var_ampl)
ent_ampl.grid(column=1,row=0)

#Frecuencia
lbl_frec = tk.Label(fr_datos_entrada, text="Frecuencia [Hz]:")
lbl_frec.grid(column=0, row=1)

var_frec = tk.StringVar(value='60')
ent_frec = tk.Entry(fr_datos_entrada, textvariable = var_frec)

ent_frec.grid(column=1, row=1)
#Fase Inicial
lbl_fase = tk.Label(fr_datos_entrada, text='Fase inicial [rad]:')
lbl_fase.grid(column=0, row=2)

var_fase = tk.StringVar(value='0')
ent_fase = tk.Entry(fr_datos_entrada, textvariable = var_fase)
ent_fase.grid(column=1, row=2)
    #Botón graficar
boton = tk.Button(fr_datos_entrada, text="Graficar", command=make_plot)
boton.grid(column=2,row=1)
    #llamo funcion
make_plot()

#No se

ventana.update()
ventana.minsize(ventana.winfo_width(), ventana.winfo_height())
ventana.maxsize(ventana.winfo_width(), ventana.winfo_height())
#Ejecuto la aplicacion
ventana.mainloop()

si existe alguien que tuviese la capacidad como para resolver este problema estaría demasiado agradecido, básicamente el problema del programa es que al darle al boton dicho para graficar no quiere generarme ningún gráfico, yo no entiendo porque eso es así, si alguien pudiese explicármelo, se supone que tiene que generar un gráfico como si fuese una onda pero cuando le das al botón sale como si la pantalla se hubiese refrescado pero no hay nada

El problema es que el botón llama a la función make_plot(), pero esta función no realiza ningún gráfico. Debes mover el código que genera los datos y la gráfica dentro de make_plot(), así:

Define las variables t, v, w, Vp, fre, fi dentro de make_plot().
Coloca la lógica de cálculo de puntos y generación del gráfico dentro de make_plot().

Además, asegura que el código que actualiza el gráfico también esté dentro de esta función.
Fácil:
import math
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2Tk as Toolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


def make_plot():
    # Crear señal
    Vp = float(var_ampl.get())  # Voltios
    fre = float(var_frec.get())  # Hercios
    w = 2 * math.pi * fre  # rad/s
    fi = float(var_fase.get())  # Rad

    # Función de la señal
    def f1(t):
        return Vp * math.sin(w * t + fi)

    # Listas con datos a graficar
    t = []
    v = []

    ciclos = 5
    puntos = 30  # Puntos por ciclo
    T = 1 / fre  # Periodo
    deltat = T / puntos  # distancia entre puntos

    ti = 0  # Tiempo inicial
    # Calculo parejas de puntos
    for i in range(puntos * ciclos + 1):
        t.append(ti)
        v.append(f1(ti))
        ti += deltat

    # Limpiar gráfico previo
    sub_figure.clear()
    sub_figure.plot(t, v)
    fig_canvas.draw()

# Construcción de la ventana y sus controles
ventana = tk.Tk()  # Ventana principal
ventana.title("Crear Gráfica")

# Frame para entregar entry y botón
fr_datos_entrada = tk.Frame(ventana)
fr_datos_entrada.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Amplitud
lbl_ampl = tk.Label(fr_datos_entrada, text="Amplitud [V]:")
lbl_ampl.grid(column=0, row=0)

var_ampl = tk.StringVar(value='100')
ent_ampl = tk.Entry(fr_datos_entrada, textvariable=var_ampl)
ent_ampl.grid(column=1, row=0)

# Frecuencia
lbl_frec = tk.Label(fr_datos_entrada, text="Frecuencia [Hz]:")
lbl_frec.grid(column=0, row=1)

var_frec = tk.StringVar(value='60')
ent_frec = tk.Entry(fr_datos_entrada, textvariable=var_frec)
ent_frec.grid(column=1, row=1)

# Fase Inicial
lbl_fase = tk.Label(fr_datos_entrada, text="Fase inicial [rad]:")
lbl_fase.grid(column=0, row=2)

var_fase = tk.StringVar(value='0')
ent_fase = tk.Entry(fr_datos_entrada, textvariable=var_fase)
ent_fase.grid(column=1, row=2)

# Botón graficar
boton = tk.Button(fr_datos_entrada, text="Graficar", command=make_plot)
boton.grid(column=2, row=1)

# Crear objetos en tk
fr_grafica = tk.Frame(ventana)
fr_grafica.grid(row=1, column=0)

figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 4))
sub_figure = figure.add_subplot(111)
fig_canvas = FigureCanvas(figure, master=fr_grafica)
fig_canvas.draw()
fig_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
fig_canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# Barra de herramientas
toolbar = Toolbar(fig_canvas, fr_grafica)
toolbar.update()

ventana.update()
ventana.minsize(ventana.winfo_width(), ventana.winfo_height())
ventana.maxsize(ventana.winfo_width(), ventana.winfo_height())
# Ejecuto la aplicación
ventana.mainloop()


Si la solución proporcionada resuelve el problema, no te olvides marcarla como aceptada, para mantener el sitio limpio.
